# What motherboards support 6 GB/s SSD and quad-core Intel processors

Tags: motherboard, ssd

Are there any motherboards that support 6GB/s SSD with a quad-core Intel processor (Q9550 in my case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many motherboards now support 6GB/s Sata 3 drives, however there is not any device (SSDs included) which are actually capable of anywhere near 6GBs, this is simply a theoretical maximum transfer speed.

Just make sure the motherboard supports SATA 3 and Quad Core, and it should meet your needs. Pretty much any (Intel based) motherboard released recently supports this configuration.

Comment: Thanks Wil, I had not realised that.  I thought you needed special support from the mobo to get the best out of drives like Crucial RealSSD (256).  I'll look into that some more after reading this.

Comment: The new OCZ Vertex 3 pushes the limits of SATA 3. I would look for a SATA 6 motherboard from now on.

Comment: I think this is incorrect, or at least I was not able to find any mobos with this combination. Please note that he is asking for socket 775 motherboard, not the newer ones.